# Create an ethereum public address from a private key

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa, private

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-an-ethereum-wallet-address-from-a-private-key-ae72b0eee27b/

Why the **secp256k1 Elliptic Curve** fail ?

```
// C#

// I am using HashLib
var ecdsaRaw = Ecdsa(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(privKey));
var ecdsaCombined = (BitConverter.ToString(ecdsaRaw.Item1) + BitConverter.ToString(ecdsaRaw.Item2)).Replace("-", "");
var finalResult = HashFactory.Crypto.SHA3.CreateKeccak256().ComputeString(ecdsaCombined, Encoding.ASCII).ToString().Replace("-", "");
var pubKey = "0x" + finalResult.Substring(finalResult.Length - 40, 40);
Console.WriteLine("ECDSA + Keccak256 : " + pubKey);

// Ecdsa Method 
public static Tuple<byte[], byte[]> Ecdsa(byte[] privateKey)
{
     var privKeyInt = new BigInteger(+1, privateKey);

     var parameters = SecNamedCurves.GetByName("secp256k1");
     var qa = parameters.G.Multiply(privKeyInt);

     var pubKeyX = qa.X.ToBigInteger().ToByteArrayUnsigned();
     var pubKeyY = qa.Y.ToBigInteger().ToByteArrayUnsigned();

     return Tuple.Create(pubKeyX, pubKeyY);
}
```

> Output :

[image]

> Expected Output :

[image]

Comment: Every time a public key is generated it is different because there is a random generator that is used to create the public key.  Even though is it different each time the decrypt code will work provided the same private key is used and the same encryption algorithm is uses.  You are failing because the same encryption algorithm is not being used to encrypt and decrypt.  One common issue is the padding option that is used in the encryption algorithm. For example Java and c# default padding options are different so data that is encrypted in java does not get decrypted properly in c#.

Comment: consider writing your comment as an answer

Comment: @jdweng The answer is not specific. You are right but I already showed all those points in the code. I m looking at the 'secp256k1 Elliptic Curve' fail. Can I get a vote up please ? I think is a valid question that doesn't have much info about online.

Comment: Then encryption key parameters are not the same as the decryption is expecting.  It looks like you are outputting so the encrypt parameters are valid.  So yo uneed to find out what the receive side is expecting.